# How to add tooltip next to textbox using dojo

Tags: html, css, jsp, dojo

I am using Dojo for tooltip. When, user move over the icon the message should be displayed.

```
.claro .dijitTooltipConnector {
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 14px;
    width: 16px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I want this icon next to this DataTextBox. Who to do this? Please help

```
<td>
    <p style="padding-left: 100px;">
        <label id="acid">Date for CC:</label>
        <input dojoType="dijit/form/DateTextBox" name="datecc" id="datecid" style="width:200px;" maxlength="50" />
    </p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`dijit/Tooltip`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Tooltip.html)?

A simplified example from the documentation:

```
<button id="buttonId" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Button Text</button>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Tooltip" data-dojo-props="connectId:'buttonId',position:['above']">
    Tooltip Content
</div>
```

So in your case you probably want a `dijit/Tooltip` whose connectId value refers to `datecid` and whose `position` value is `['left','right']` or whatever your position preferences are. (If it can't fit on the left, it'll go right as its second-choice.)

Note that this example uses HTML ID values, but other examples can show CSS selectors. (I've made a custom subclass that supports attach-point names, but it's still very experimental and hacky.)

Answer (score 2):

Try using "dijit.showTooltip()" to show the tooltip at any place instantly, without need to write any HTML code for tooltips. (similarly, "dijit.hideTooltip" for hiding the same). Let me give a small example of how you can use it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/_static/js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src="http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/_static/js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dijit/Tooltip"]);
function showTooltip() {
    var domNode = dijit.byId('datefld').domNode; //domNode to which the tooptip must point to
    dijit.showTooltip("Enter your date of birth here!!", domNode,["above"]); // you can use "above" or "below" or "right" or "left"
}
function hideTooltip() {
    var domNode = dijit.byId('datefld').domNode;
    dijit.hideTooltip(domNode);
}
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<label for="firstname">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" id="firstname"  promptMessage="Enter your name here!"/><br/><br/>
<label for="firstname">DOB : </label>
<input type="text" name="datefld" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" id="datefld" promptMessage="Enter your date of birth here!"/>
<br/><br/>
<span onmouseover="showTooltip()" onmouseout="hideTooltip()">hover here for tip!!</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: This is a bit legacy way of coding mixed with the new AMD design. But, this would be more elegant for your scenario.

Comment: I believe the [dijit/Tooltip documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Tooltip.html) shows the modern style under the heading "Ad-Hoc Popup".